# how to convert .c file to .hex file and load it on AVR microcontroller?

Tags: c, hex, bootloader, hex-file

I need a compiler to convert .c files to .hex file in command line
and I need information about how its work
thanks a lot

Comment: avr-gcc and avrdude come to mind, but your question is way too general. Anyhow, the internet is full of tutorials to get started with AVR ATMega MCU, especially because it's used in Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the target is for your application.  If this is being loaded onto a microprocessor, which is why I am assuming you need a hex file, you will need to download the compiler for the microprocessor. This can probably be obtained on the chip manufacturer website.  Once you acquire this you will need to compile, link and map your project, which will result in some sort of output file such as a combined-object file format (COFF) file.  For the microprocessor I am using, the manufacturer also provides a converter that converts the COFF file to hex format.  The hex file can then be used to load the firmware on to a chip.

Comment: For added confusion, there is more than one hex format, (eg. Intel hex and Motorola S-record), and more than one way of getting the file onto the controller, (load into RAM using serial boot loader, load into flash using serial boot loader, in-application flash loading, loading with JTAG debugger).